# Cannot use childNodeWithName with a Sprite with a parent defined in SKS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKS file with a Color Sprite defined as a box, and a Label in it. The Label parent is the box, so when I use:

```
let box = childNodeWithName("mybox") as SKSpriteNode
let labeltxt = childNodeWithName("mylabel") as SKLabelNode
```

The program returns an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Someone knows how to change the value of the text of "mylabel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the label is a child of box you create a constant declaring the label node

```
let labeltxt = box.childNodeWithName("mylabel") as SKLabelNode
```

Comment: Thank you, it was so helpful :)

Comment: Just as an aside: you could also have used childNodeWithName("mybox/mylabel") as SKLabelNode and avoid the first line.